# Tensor Flow Could not load custom protobuf files in

Tags: android, python-2.7, protocol-buffers, tensorflow

I have just created a protobuf file (`.pb` file) for my own custom images using a [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html).

But when I replaced the same file into the assets folder in `tensorflow/examples/android/assets` and try to build and generate an APK, the APK gets generated, but when I run the APK in an Android device, the APK crashes.

If I run the `classify_image` from Python, it gives me proper results.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you check if the APK does contain the PB files you expect? Also, it may help to get some error trace and more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Since DecodeJpeg isn't supported as part of the core, you'll need to strip it out of the graph first.

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:strip_unused && \
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/strip_unused \
--input_graph=your_retrained_graph.pb \
--output_graph=stripped_graph.pb \
--input_node_names=Mul \
--output_node_names=final_result \
--input_binary=true
```

Change few parameters in this file

/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageListener.java

The input sizes need to be 299, not 224. You'll also need to change the mean and std values both to 128.

INPUT_NAME to "Mul:0" ,
OUTPUT_NAME to "final_result:0"

after which you will be able to compile the apk.

Good Luck

Comment: Hi Rohit, are you using TensorFlow 0.10.0rc0? When I run `bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/strip_unused` I get the error `from tensorflow.python.tools import strip_unused_lib
ImportError: No module named tools`.. Thanks, Jeff

Comment: i am on r0.9.  its "tools:strip_unused" not "tools/strip_unused"    just run the entire command at once on the terminal from your workspace and make sure your .pb file is present in your workspace as well